# Golang RPC server Docker Automatic Deployment

Tags: go, config, microservices

I want to deploy golang rpc servers to different docker images. How or what is the best practice for auto configuring these images.

For instance, if I have 3 different RPC servers, for 3 different purposes. I want to deploy them as three independent docker instances with different IPs. And some how let the main server contact them automatically. Is there a way or tool to do this?

I am using gorilla rpc, rpc/json and mux packages by the way.

Comment: The main server is the server that hosts the Docker containers?

Comment: main server could be another go http server running in a different docker image instance